# CiviCRM - Contribution page profiles JavaScript error

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, backbone

before you send me to check already solved similar questions, this is not the same case.

Common problem is conflict with installed plugins -> disable/enabled them all, none, different order = nothing (I dont have jetpack, google dashboard, wp cards)

Another cause is template -> changed template, no difference but if I add Civi into blank Wordpress instalation it works.

Does anyone have same experience that it cannot be fixed with the "common" way ? And if yes did you manage to fix it ?

[image: js error]

Comment: By template, do you mean theme?

Comment: Yes :) Seems like it conflict with Civi by default.

Answer (score 1):

Try using one of the basic WordPress Themes like Twenty Seventeen or Twenty Sixteen. If it works with one of these themes, pick a new theme that you like.

You probably have to pick a theme from another company altogether. The theme designer probably has a base package that he/she uses and the problem will follow from theme to theme in their suite.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I contacted the theme creators and get answer that it is no way that the theme is causing this problem and when I change template to the basic one that you mentioned, error stay.

On the other hand when I installed new wordpress on sub-domain with default theme and installed CiviCRM, it worked perfectly.

Comment: What version of WP and Civi are you using? Is the install that you are having trouble with a new install or has it been functioning? Is the WP/Civi versions the same on your problem install as they are in your new test install?

Comment: WP 4.8.2 CIvi  4.7.24. It has never been fully functioning. Yes versions are same on the old one non-functioning as on the new fresh functioning.

Comment: I am using WP 4.8.2 Civi 4.7.25. I get the exact same errors and cannot edit profiles on contribution pages. I had this for as long as I have been using Civi (2016).  My theme creator told me that same thing but I have had developers look at it and it is a Civi/Theme conflict. Rather than paying for a patch, I just switch to the WP TwentySeverteen or TwentySixteen theme. Then go back to Manage Contribution > Profiles and set them to what I want. Go back to Themes and switch back to my normal theme. It screws up my site for a few minutes but is a workable fix.

Comment: The profile widget uses backbone.js and if your theme or a plugin also includes that library then they can conflict. There is an issue to make civi use backbone.js in no-conflict mode, but for now you can't use WordPress themes or plugins that include it

Comment: I believe this has been fixed in 4.7.30